# dbms_lob.getlength() vs. length() to find blob size in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

I'm getting the same results from

```
select length(column_name) from table
```

as from

```
select dbms_lob.getlength(column_name) from table
```

However, the answers to
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840966/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-return-a-readable-file-size-of-a-file-stored-in-an-or) seem to favor using `dbms_lob.getlength()`.

Is there any benefit to using `dbms_lob.getlength()`?

If it changes the answer, I know all of the BLOBs are `.bmp` images (never worked with BLOBs before).

Answer (score 139, accepted):

[`length`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm#i77725) and [`dbms_lob.getlength`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998484) return the number of characters when applied to a **CLOB** (Character LOB). When applied to a **BLOB** (Binary LOB), `dbms_lob.getlength` will return the number of bytes, which may differ from the number of characters in a multi-byte character set.

As the documentation doesn't specify what happens when you apply `length` on a BLOB, I would advise against using it in that case. If you want the number of bytes in a BLOB, use `dbms_lob.getlength`.

Comment: Or if you know you are working with BLOBs and not CLOBs or NCLOBs use lengthb(BLOB) to get the number of bytes in the BLOB.