# Selecting big size docs from oracle db

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

So want to get Id's of documents which are bigger than 60 mb:

```
SELECT

DOCS.ID

FROM DOCS

where LENGTH(DOCS.DOCUMENT) > (60*1024*1024)
```

and I get this error : 
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG BINARY
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
document is savad as a long raw ...
probably should cast somehow to long???

The only solution I came up with was To alter table from long raw to BLOB, then for some divine reason you have to recreate ALL indexes for that table... it's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this is a problem, but you can use PL/SQL as a workaround:

```
create or replace function get_doc_length(iDocId in number) return number is
  aLong long;
begin
  select d.document into aLong from docs d where d.id = iDocId;

  return length(aLong);
end;
/
```

This function (which cannot use a `LONG` as parameter, unfortunately, so must be specific to table `DOCS`) can then be used like this:

```
SELECT DOCS.ID
FROM DOCS
where get_doc_length(DOCS.ID) > (60*1024*1024)
```

**EDIT** : ok, this does not work for big `LONG`s. You have to dig even more into SQL's arcanes to make this work:

```
create or replace function get_doc_length(iDocId in number) return number is
  myQuery  varchar2(200);
  myCursor binary_integer;
  myRes    pls_integer;
  myDoc    clob;

  long_val long;
  long_len integer;
  buf_len  integer;
  cur_pos  number;
begin

  myQuery := 'select d.document from docs d where d.id = ' || iDocId;

  -- Create cursor, parse and bind.
  myCursor := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(myCursor, myQuery, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN_LONG(myCursor, 01);

  myRes := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(myCursor);

  -- Fetch row (only one normally)
  if DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(myCursor) > 0 then
    -- Create CLOB.
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(myDoc, false, DBMS_LOB.CALL);

    -- Piecewise fetching of the LONG column, appending to the CLOB.
    buf_len := 32760;
    cur_pos := 0;
    loop
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE_LONG(myCursor, 01, buf_len, cur_pos, long_val, long_len);
      exit when long_len = 0;
      DBMS_LOB.APPEND(myDoc, long_val);
      cur_pos := cur_pos + long_len;
    end loop;
  end if;

  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(myCursor);

  return length(myDoc);
end;
/
```

The `DBMS_SQL` package allows to convert a `LONG` into a `CLOB` by looping on it and appending pieces of the `LONG` gradually.

If you want the binary length of the `CLOB` instead of its char length (this may differ), you can use `dbms_lob.getlength` instead of `length` as [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373138/dbms-lob-getlength-vs-length-to-find-blob-size-in-oracle) shows.

Comment: is there a way to do this without a stored procedure?

Comment: I did not find any, as I could see on several other posts while googling. This is a pity, since you are forced to create basically one function of this type per LONG field you want to get...

Comment: With smaller docs this works but when we have to deal with bigger ones this is what i get...Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "xxx.GET_DOC_LENGTH", line 10
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"

Comment: I have a solution using LONG to CLOB conversion, see my edit.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this function throws this errror, also I think we could try using BLOB's instead of CLOBS Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG BINARY
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1575
ORA-06512: at "SOS.GET_DOC_LENGTH", line 20
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DOCS.ID
FROM DOCS
WHERE dbms_lob.getlength(DOCS.DOCUMENT) > (60*1024*1024)
```

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"